# ASP.NET CheckBox runat="server" name issue

Tags: asp.net, html

When i using checkbox `runat="server"` in my asp.net web application.
Then browsers have a problem:

> Uncaught Syntax error, unrecognized expression:
>   [name=ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$FormPlaceHolder$CrossFinancing]

ASP.NET code is:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="CrossFinancing" id="CrossFinancing" runat="server" />
```

Generated html code is:

```
<input name="ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$FormPlaceHolder$CrossFinancing" type="checkbox" id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_FormPlaceHolder_CrossFinancing" />
```

What is a problem with this name? This is generated by asp.net and
browers dont parse this correctly, other controls have '$' in name and
this works.

Comment: The generated html is a textbox, not a checkbox..?

Comment: Is type="text" or should that be type="checkbox"?

Comment: fixed, i pasted not this line i should

Comment: Where exactly do you see this error and which browser have you tested? Any javascript on the page?

Comment: Are you using this name attribute in javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you let the ASP.net runtime generate the checkbox for you??

```
<asp:CheckBox id="chkCrossFinancing" runat="server"/>
```

The name attribute will be managed by the ASP.net runtime itself.